# C#: restore SQL Server DB from a backup inside an embedded resource

Tags: c#, sql-server, embedded-resource

I have a file that contains a SQL Server 2012 database backup. I am using this file with a C# WinForms application, that creates a database, restores the backup into it, and then performs some more functions.

I don't want to just add this backup file to my application, because this is a security issue. I was thinking I should add the backup as an embedded resource, and then save it to a temp file, restore from it and delete it.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to access an embedded resource directly through a file path that I can pass to SQL server to use in the RESTORE DATABASE command?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has no idea whatsoever about how to restore a database from something living inside an executable.  Given that you state that you've considered it be able to be an embedded resource, I am going to assume that it's not a "last known good" backup, but more a "default" backup.

If I am correct in this thinking, then you're basically saying you have a default set-up.  If that is the case, you don't need a backup at all, your code just needs to be able to create a database and populate it with certain things to "become" that default state.  By embedding a backup as a resource, you are (in my mind) stating that the structure and data is well known, so why go down the `RESTORE DATABASE` path at all?

Comment: I could do what you suggest, but this default database has several hundreds of tables, thousands of stored procedures, and several hunders of lines of built-in data.
It is a lot easier to manage as a real database. Therefore, when it is time to deploy, it is much easier to create a backup and store it somewhere than to create a script that will contain tens of thousands of lines of code, and test it each time.
Also, I'm pretty sure that running the script will take longer than restoring.
Also... in general, dealing with code execution seems like more of a headache than restoring.

Comment: @user884248, well you make a good point if the database is as big as you say it is.  You *could* store it as a binary resource and then write it to disk for SQL Server to find (and then delete it) - but that'll make the executable obscenely huge just for a one-time thing.  Another option might be to have it in a passworded zip file which you can extract on startup and do the same thing.  Not foolproof and definitely hackable, but whatever you do - if you're deploying a database at setup, this is going to be an issue if security is a consideration.

Comment: Thanks MooJuice, I appreciate the advice!